# `Package fontspec Warning: Font XXX does not contain requested Script "CJK"`, but visually it does

Tags: luatex, fontspec, cjk

I have below warning in LuaLaTeX/ltjsarticle project:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc" does not contain
requested Script "CJK".
```

I dot't know about Chinese and Korean, but Japanese language displaying correctly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\edef\ProjectAbsolutePath{\directlua{tex.sprint((lfs.currentdir():gsub('\string\\', '/')))}/}

\setmainjfont[
  Path            = \ProjectAbsolutePath,
  UprightFont     = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
  BoldFont        = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc,
  ItalicFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
  BoldItalicFont  = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{HGS Mincho}

\setsansjfont[
  Path            = \ProjectAbsolutePath,
  UprightFont     = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
  BoldFont        = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc,
  ItalicFont      = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
  BoldItalicFont  = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc
]{HGS Gothic}


\begin{document}

\section{活字試験}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item 主要活字
    \begin{itemize}
      \item 漢あア
      \item \bfseries{漢あア}
    \end{itemize}
    \item ゴシック活字
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textsf{漢あア}
      \item \textsf{\bfseries{漢あア}}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Why this warning appears and how I can correctly solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually specify the script with `fontspec`.

This should work (although I don't have the font to test).

```
\setmainjfont[
  Path            = \ProjectAbsolutePath,
  UprightFont     = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
  BoldFont        = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc,
  ItalicFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
  BoldItalicFont  = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc,
  Script          = Default
]{HGS Mincho}
```

**Update:** Apparently, this font does not support a `Default` script either :(.

Therefore, the easiest option will be to suppress the warnings with `fontspec`. From §3.4 of the `fontspec` manual, passing `quiet` will put these warnings in the `log` file, and `silent` will suppress the warnings altogether.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{quiet}{fontspec}% (or try silent)
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I got `Package fontspec Warning: Font "fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc" does not contain
(fontspec)  requested Script "Default".` instead.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, that's a pity. These are commercial fonts, right? Without opening them up in a font editor and seeing what is going on, I'm not sure what to try.

Comment: oh, I see. Would you please to recommend some font editor?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, [`fontforge`](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is the tool of choice in the Open Source world. It is also possible to suppress just `fontspec` warnings by either passing `quiet` or `silent` to `fontspec`. I'll make a note of this in my answer.

Comment: O'K, I accepted your answer! Thanks again for explanations.